# How to implement Exception/Error Handling in Swift 4 with native Crash Reporting?

Tags: ios, swift, crash, swift4

I want to implement **native crash reporting** (*without using 3rd party library recommended*) in my **iOS Swift 4 code** and inform to my back end server with **API call** when the **App Crashes** or generating any **exceptions**. I found that App Store / iTunes Connect provides number of Crashes but it **does not provide Crash information** like from which UIViewController or from due to which error it crashed. Could anyone help me out in this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is extremely difficult to do correctly and has a high likelihood of causing significant problems in your app (there are worse things than crashing; I've done them trying to build one of these). There are many non-obvious corner cases when dealing with a program in a undefined state. (You can't allocate heap memory for instance.) I strongly recommend using an established third-party crash collector. If you want to manage your own backend, PLCrashReporter is an opensource solution. They've been doing this for 10 years. You want that kind of experience for this.

Comment: BTW, you don't mean "generating any exceptions." You mean "certain kinds of unhandled exceptions that crash your app." And you really just mean "crashes." (Even the word "exceptions" covers at least four unrelated-to-slightly-related things in a Cocoa program.) This is pedantic, but critical, and the kind of thing that causes home-grown crash-reporters to break their app. There are several things that generate exceptions that you don't want to catch for one of the several meanings of "exception." If you decide to go this way (to learn, for instance), at least study PLCrashReporter as a basis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes for that you have to make your custom crash report manager and you can use `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler` for getting the crash report stack.

**Example**

```
NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler { exception in

    print(exception)
    print(exception.callStackSymbols)

    // Write callStackSymbols into the file
    // Call your mail function with that file
    // mail()
}

let array = NSArray()
let element = array.object(at: 4)
```

You can write that Crash Report into the file and mail it.

Comment: is it possible to make API call with crash data on above function instead of calling mail function?

Comment: @iajmeri43 Yes, you can create .crash file and send that file to your server using API

Comment: Dear Sanjay
I'm trying to use this code in my project which is swift 4, and I get this error: "A C function pointer cannot be formed from a closure that captures context". what should I do?

Comment: @Niloufar Can you please share screenshot for the error.

Answer (score 3):

As you told in question that, iTunes is providing only number of crashes, but **does not provide crash information**.

In reality, **XCode** itself provides you full fledged detail of crash with line number, device information, build detail etc all things.

HereIn, I am describing how you can get **detail of crashes from Xcode**

1. Go to 'Window' -> 'Organizer' in xcode

[image]

2. New window get opened, select your app name from left sided list of apps, and select `Crashes` from top segment control.

[image]

3. Now, You can select the version that you want(Even you can select the Beta build that you uploaded on testflight), once you select version, you will get all the crashes of that version. You can see in below image that, it shows details of device, details of thread etc.

[image]

4. Now, if you want to go to the line, where crash happened. Just hover at bold line in crash detail, you will see arrow button as in below image. Once you click that button, Xcode will redirect you to related line in your project.

[image]

I think, it is now clear to you, about how to see the crashes from the live app.

Comment: nice answer, by d way I want to send it also to my back-end server with API calling on which Controller & or from which error / exception caused. Hope u got it my requirement.